# Controlling GDirections mini-popup-maps

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Google Maps API to code a campus map for my university.  On the main map, when it is being viewed in the "Map" maptype, there is a custom overlay of the campus, which is set (by using GEvent.addDomListener) to be removed when the map is viewed in Satellite or Hybrid mode.  When the user gets directions, through my map, to and from the campus, a polyline and 2 markers show up, like normal.  When the marker is clicked, a small popup map is display, focused on the area of campus around that particular marker.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to set attributes of these mini-popup-maps.  I need to extend the event listener to make sure that the overlay gets taken off when the mini map is clicked out of "Map" mode.  I also need to be able to set the zoom level for these maps.

Any ideas?

(code can be provided as needed, wasn't really sure what parts would be needed and didn't want to post the whole f'n thing up here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like there are any built in options to modify the *infoWindow* you get from the *GDirection* markers, but you can explicitly replace the markers once you get them back.

[This post](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleMapsAPI/2009-02/msg00208.html) describes the process.